# Journey Builder errors alert

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I have a question about errors notification in Journey Builder.  Is there a possibility to receive a notification when a journey run with errors, or to build a custom report with Journey's Errors?

Thanks

Comment: Might worth asking on http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

If the journey has inherent errors, Journey Builder most likely won't let you activate it. 

-The easiest way to find errors is to click the "Validate" button (top-right corner of canvas). This checks the basics such as entry source, entry mode, schedule, activities, goals (if defined), and exit criteria (if defined). 

-Remember to "save" first before validating the journey

Journey Builder has 2 reports available, but I don't believe it processes errors from activities or email sends.

If you're looking to find errors with journey builder email sends, I recommend setting up Send Logging.

-https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_send_logging.htm&type=5

-Note: Cross-cloud and custom activities are not validated during this check process.